# React upload multiple files at once in an input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make an input that could take a folder/winrar of images and upload them all at once, and then display them on the page. I made it that it takes up one at the time, but I was wondering if there is a possible way to make it upload multiple files at once

Answer (score 1):

**It would be similar to the native HTML, for React you will need to use `useRef` to handle those files to send API**

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="files">Select files:</label>
  <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Working with React:**

```js
    const FileForm = () => {
      const inputRef = React.useRef();

      const handleChangeFile = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.files);
        //OR
        console.log(inputRef.current.files)
      };

      return <input ref={inputRef} type="file" name="file" onChange={handleChangeFile} multiple />;
    };

    ReactDOM.render(<FileForm />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: So basically you're saying that by having a form and submitting the files to the API through a ref will work for files of images?

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer with example with Reactjs

Comment: Does it help you @SergiuTonț?

Comment: Might do, yes. I'll test it out. Thanks for the answer